# assign variables to an R expressions in a plot title

Tags: r, function, loops, plot, expression

can you please help me assign values in R expressions for a plot

```
#define function which takes n to genrate random numbers and asscoiated histogram
plot_sim <- function(n_sim = NULL){
  rand_var <- runif(n_sim)
  hist(rand_var, freq = F, main = expression(paste('Histogram of rand_var ',bar(X)[n = n_sim])))
}


#for  possible n run function through a for loop
possible_n = c(100,2000,400)
for (i in 1:length(possible_n)){
  plot_sim(possible_n[i])
}
```

the `n_sim` in plot title remains unchanged after loops
[image]

Comment: also, `main = parse(text = sprintf('Histogram~of~rand_var~bar(X)[%s]', n_sim))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way using `bquote` -

```
plot_sim <- function(n_sim = NULL){
  rand_var <- runif(n_sim)
  hist(rand_var, freq = F, 
        main = bquote(paste('Histogram of rand_var ',~bar(X)[n = .(n_sim)])))
}


#for  possible n run function through a for loop
possible_n = c(100,2000,400)
for (i in 1:length(possible_n)){
  plot_sim(possible_n[i])
}
```

[image]